# CSS, div fixed size

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple website, but struggling with its layout.

This is what I have to do:

[image]

and this is what I did:

```
<div id="cabecalho">

<div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Advocacia" /><img src="img/inico.png" alt="IN" id="inico" /><img src="img/twitterico.png" alt="Twitter" id="twitterico" /></div>


<div id="escritorio">ESCRITÓRIO</div><div id="atuacao">ATUAÇÃO</div><div id="contatos">CONTATOS</div><div id="artigos">ARTIGOS</div>


</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
body{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#logo {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;   
}
#twitterico{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#inico{
    float: right;
}
#cabecalho{
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
#escritorio{
    background-color:#243655;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#atuacao{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-top: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    color:#243655;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;  

}
#contatos{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 19.7%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-top: 1px solid #aab1bd;  
    color:#243655;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;  

}
#artigos{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-top: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    border-right: 1px solid #aab1bd;
    color:#243655;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
```

so, the problem is that when I resize the window, the layout is completely screwed...

How can I solve that?

Is there a better way to do everything I did?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use media queries or use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Responsive Design. Depending on the current screen size (or in your case browser window), you have to rearange/shrink/remove different elements so that they can all fit on the screen. Learn how to do it here: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/